# Rectangle.java Won't Return Correct Length and Width

Tags: java, rectangles, getmethod

I'm new to stackoverflow, and I'm working on a project for a class of mine (specifically CSC 202J), and I'm almost done, but I 'm having a small problem- the input feature is not working correctly. The I've programmed this so that the rectangle has a default width and length of 1.0, but when I call either of the get methods, I see that neither value has changed. I'll provide my code (along with the driver class and the requirements of the assignment, along with the output of a test run.

Assignment:

> Create a class Rectangle. The class has attributes length and width, each
>   of which defaults to  1. Provide methods that calculate the perimeter and the area of the rectangle.
>   Provide set and get methods for both length and width. The set methods
>   should verify that length and width are each floating-point numbers greater than or equal to 0.0 and less than 20.0.
>   Write a program to test class Rectangle.

SAMPLE OUTPUT:

```
1. Set Length
2. Set Width
3. Exit
Choice: 1
Enter Length: 10
Length: 10.00
Width: 1.00
Perimeter: 22.00
Area: 10.00
1. Set Length
2. Set Width
3. Exit
Choice: 2
Enter Width: 15
Length: 10.00
Width: 15.00
Perimeter: 50.00
Area: 150.00
1. Set Length
2. Set Width
3. Exit
Choice: 1
Enter Length: 1
Length: 1.00
Width: 15.00
Perimeter: 32.00
Area: 15.00
1. Set Length
2. Set Width
3. Exit
Choice: 3
```

Classes:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class RectangleTest {
public static void main (String[] args)
{
   int response = 0;
   Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
   Rectangle r = new Rectangle();

     do{

      System.out.println("1. Set Length");
      System.out.println("2. Set Width");
      System.out.println("3. Exit");
      System.out.println("Choice: ");
      response = userInput.nextInt();

        if(response == 1)
        {
            System.out.println("Enter Length: ");
            r.setLength(userInput.nextInt());
            r.toString();
            System.out.println("Length: " + r.getLength());
            System.out.println("Width: " + r.getWidth());
            System.out.println("Perimeter: " + r.perimeter());
            System.out.println("Area: " + r.area());
        }
        if(response == 2)
        {
            System.out.println("Enter Width: ");
            r.setWidth(userInput.nextInt());
            r.toString();
            System.out.println("Length: " + r.getLength());
            System.out.println("Width: " + r.getWidth());
            System.out.println("Perimeter: " + r.perimeter());
            System.out.println("Area: " + r.area()); 
        }
      }
    while(response != 3);
    System.exit(0);
  }

}



public class Rectangle {
    private double length;
    private double width;

public Rectangle(){
    this.length = 1.0;
    this.width = 1.0;
  }

public double getLength(){
    return this.length;
  }

public double getWidth(){
   return this.width;
  }

public boolean setLength(double length){
   if (length > 0.0 && 1 < 20.0){
      return true;
   }
    return false;
 }

public boolean setWidth(double width){
    if(width > 0.0 && width < 20.0){
       return true;
   }
    return false;
}

public double perimeter(){
   return 2 * (this.length + this.width);
}

public double area(){
   return this.getLength() * this.getWidth();
}

@Override
public String toString(){
   return "Length: " + this.length +"\tWidth: " + this.width;
}

}
```

Test Run Output:

```
1. Set Length
2. Set Width
3. Exit
Choice: 
1
Enter Length: 
10
Length: 1.0
Width: 1.0
Perimeter: 4.0
Area: 1.0
1. Set Length
2. Set Width
3. Exit
Choice: 
2
Enter Width: 
14
Length: 1.0
Width: 1.0
Perimeter: 4.0
Area: 1.0
1. Set Length
2. Set Width
3. Exit
Choice: 
3
```

I apologize if this is a rookie mistake that I'm overlooking.

Comment: in your `setLength` Method: `if (length > 0.0 && 1 < 20.0)` shouldn't this be `length` instead of `1`??

Comment: `1` is always going to be less than `20.0` in your code. Next, you never actually save the value passed into your `setXXX()` methods. So the values are never changed.

Comment: very true, that's been corrected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never set the value in your `setXXX()` methods. Include `this.width = width` and `this.length = length` in your code.

```
public class Rectangle {
    private double width;
    private double length;

    public boolean setWidth(double width) {
        if(width >= 0.0 && width < 20.0) {
            this.width = width; // <<< You need this line ...
            return true;
        } else return false;
    }

    public boolean setLength(double length) {
        if(length >= 0.0 && length < 20.0) {
            this.length = length; // <<< ... and this one, too!
            return true;
        } else return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah ha! Added that piece of code, and it's working now. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score -1):

In order to change the values of the rectangle class you would have to do the following:

```
public void setwidth(double width){
    if (width => 0.0 && width < 20.0){
        this.width = width;
    }
}
```

The same would would apply for the length. At the moment your code returns a Boolean indicating whether the input width is within certain values. The set methods do not need to return anything.

I noticed another error in your code, in the setLength method;

```
public boolean setLength(double length){
   if (length > 0.0 && 1 < 20.0){
      return true;
   }
    return false;
   }
```

Were you intending to type `length` in the if statement where it says `if (length> 0.0 && 1 < 20.0)` ?

Another note: in your assignment description it is stated that the width and length need to be "greater or equal than zero", so in code the if statement would look like `if (width >= 0.0 && width < 20.0)`. Note the greater or equal than symbol.

Comment: Because he is checking if the values are within a certain range, returning a `boolean` is a valid way of checking if the property could be properly set.